# Replace First Character PHP

Tags: php

I want to check user input in the textbox. If the first character is a zero, it will be replaced with `+63`. But it should not replace all the zeroes in the string. I had search through sites but most are about replacing all of the occurrences. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Wait. PHP or Javascript? You received a bunch of answers for JS, since that's what your original question was for.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In PHP:

```
<?php 
$ptn = "/^0/";  // Regex
$str = "01234"; //Your input, perhaps $_POST['textbox'] or whatever
$rpltxt = "+63";  // Replacement string
echo preg_replace($ptn, $rpltxt, $str);
?>
```

Would echo out:

```
+631234
```

Of course, you'll want to validate the input and everything, but that's how you'd replace it after it's been submitted.

Answer (score 9):

**JavaScript solution**

```
var str = "000123";
var foo = str.replace(/^0/,"+63");
alert(foo);
```

Basic regular expression

- ^ - match beginning of a string
- 0 - match the number zero

**PHP Solution**

```
$string = '000123';
$pattern = '/^0/';
$replacement = '+63';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

Comment: i am sorry.. i am talking about php.. i placed a wrong javascript question

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
if(oldStr.charAt(0) == "0") {
  newStr= oldStr.replace(oldStr.charAt(0), "+63");
}
```

Btw its JS solution

Comment: @roman Oh really.... I guess that was that was added later.. Else y do u think so many JS related answers.. Just to get a downvote.....?

Comment: Can you please add that it's a JS version I will be able to revote after it.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend avoid Regex in your code if you can due to performance overhead. It's easy to make it **in PHP** without Regex:

```
if($str[0] == "0"){
    $str = substr_replace($str,'+63',0,1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand everything correctly this should work for you:

```
<input type="text" id="txt" value="0 is the score" />
```

Javascript:

```
​var str = document.getElementById("txt").value;
if(str[0] === '0') {
 document.getElementById("txt").value = "63" + str.substring(1);
}
```

See **demo** : http://jsfiddle.net/rZ3vm/

Also see [string functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) in javascript and the [substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) function.

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "000123";
var foo = str.charAt(0).replace("0","+63") + str.substr(1);
alert(foo);
```

Answer (score 0):

Some thing like this ....

```
var string = "0230234";

var newString = string.indexOf('0') == 0 ? string.substring(1) : string;

newString = "+63"+newString 

alert(newString); // +63230234
```

Answer (score 0):

```
str=(str.charAt(0)=='0')?(str.replace(str.charAt(0),"+63")):str;
```

[check this](http://jsfiddle.net/WAs4j/)

Answer (score 0):

```
 $numbers='012345';
```

1.first check the first digit is zero or not,

```
 if (preg_match('/^0/', $numbers))
```

2.if zero,then remove zero and add the required data with the variable

```
$str=ltrim ($numbers, '0');
$mobile ='+63'.$str;
```

so the output will be,

```
          +6312345
```